# Prism Line Numbers Plugin not working correctly

Tags: linux, reactjs, docker, line-numbers

We have the following React code

```
 return <div> 
            <div>linesStart is: {linesStart}</div>
            <pre id={id} className="line-numbers" data-start={linesStart}>
                <code className={`language-${language}`}>
                    {children}
                </code>
            </pre>
        </div>;
```

1. `{linesStart}` is calculated correctly - as we verify in the first div.
2. `{linesStart}` is passed to `data-start` for the Prism **Line-Numbers Plugin**.
3. The line numbers always show correctly when compiling and running from **Rider or Visual Studio**.
4. But, when publishing and running from **the console, or through the DockerFile**, the start number is always '1', 
    no matter what value is passed to the line-numbers plugin with variable 'linesStart' !!

So, for example, even if we have `data-start={5}`,
 **the line numberings will start from '1', instead of from '5'**. 
Any ideas ?

Contents of Dockerfile are:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env

WORKDIR /app

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs 

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore \ 
    && cd DemoServer \
    && dotnet publish -c Debug -o out

FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
ENV RAVENDEMO_Database__Urls__0="http://live-test.ravendb.net" RAVENDEMO_Database__Name="Demo" RAVENDEMO_ConferenceMode=false COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/DemoServer/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DemoServer.dll"]
```

Running the below in the console (windows & linux) produce the issue as well:

```
  dotnet publish -c Release -o out
  cd ./out
  dotnet DemoServer.dll
```

---

[image]

Comment: Any ideas about what? You don't really state a problem or ask a question.

Comment: Ideas about why the line-numbers always start with '1', even when code has ```data-start={5}```, for example